# Error collect2: cannot find 'ld' while building wxWidgets

Tags: mingw, wxwidgets, ld, mingw32

So I was trying to build wxWidgets in release mode using GCC Mingw and following [this](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets_with_MinGW) guide, so I ran the following command:
`mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release`
 and it was going all smooth for about 10 minutes when it suddenly threw this error:
`collect2: cannot find 'ld'
mingw32-make: *** [..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxbase30u_gcc_custom.dll] Error 1`

The compiler is working and I've tested it by running some code in codeblocks.
I've also tried building the source files through visual studio but it kept throwing a bunch of errors saying it can't open some include files like "commctrl.h", which "I guess" happened due to library build order issues.

So my question is what causes the `collect2: cannot find 'ld'` and how to fix it?

Comment: please post the last command that was tried to execute before throwing such an error. Also are you sure there is nothing after 'ld'? What version of MinGW do you use? Where did you take it from? Finally how did you run the build?

Comment: Post updated.
Yeah I'm sure there's nothing after 'ld', I'm not really sure what version of MinGW I'm using, it was installed alongside with codeblocks through codeblocks setup "I'm using codeblocks 17.12".

As per the guide I opened a command prompt windows, changed the directory to `wxWidgets-3.0.4\build\msw`, cleaned the project then built it using: `mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release`

Comment: MinGW version is 3.16 and GCC version is 4.4.1

Comment: this is very weird error. So what command was tried just prior to throwing that error? You should be able to just copy and paste it here as it should be still on the screen. And no, the command you posted was executed by you when you started building. What I'm looking for is the command that was tried during the build execution. So you can just re-run the command and it should give you the same error with the command.

Comment: You can also try to re-install the MinGW toolchain, since I think something went wrong during the initial install. Just uninstall the one you have right now completely and then install one on top.

Comment: Thanks Igor, MinGW was outdated, updated it and the building process went smoothly!

Comment: no problem. just to test try to build the minimal sample inside wxWidgets-3.0.4\samples\minimal. change to that directory and use exactly the same command you used to build the library. if you can successfully build and run it - everything is good.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated MinGW and all went good, make sure the path values of MinGW are updated if you install the new version in a different directory.